# Регулярки для replaceAll()

Tags: java

Помогите написать регулярку, которая оставит ТОЛЬКО цифры в строке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спасибо [@vv2cc](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/7163/vv2cc) за комментарии.

Самый оптимальный вариант:

```
someString.replaceAll("[^\\d]","");
```

Заменит все символы, кроме цифр, на пустой символ.

Comment: ./*$.... ?

Comment: Эти символы оставит. Оставил на усмотрение автора. Неизвестно, какие именно символы будут встречаться в исходном тексте.

Comment: так в условии задания - надо ТОЛЬКО цифры =)

Comment: Согласен, способ неидеальный. Действительно, лучше идти от обратного - выделить только цифры и про остальное забыть =)

Answer (score 4):

Регулярное выражение, которое выделит все кроме цифр: 
[/\D/](http://www.pcre.ru/eval/%5CD%40%3D%23%3D%40101%40%3D%23%3D%40%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B9%20123%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E.233/)

Comment: а если наоборот?)

Comment: [\d][1]


  [1]: http://www.pcre.ru/eval/%5Cd%40%3D%23%3D%40101%40%3D%23%3D%40%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B9%20123%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E.233/